# Difference between "at the time" and "at that time"

Tags: grammar

For example,

> This early 1980s incident made headlines **at that time**.

*versus*

> This early 1980s incident made headlines **at the time**.

Which is correct and why?

Answer (score -1):

First, you identify the instance

> That man robbed me. That is the man who robbed me.

Once the instance is identified, then the instance has been defined. Having been defined, means you have a definite way to point to the man. Now you can say,

> The man first stopped me with a machete. Then he relieved me of all my jewelry.

Similarly, first identify the moment.

> Kate: Joan, there was a time when we were kids and we a had a house next to a brook.
>
> Joan: That time. I remember that time. At the time we were what ... ? Four, five years old ?
>
> Kate: Yah, I was probably five, and you four. Do you remember the day our cat fell into the brook ?
>
> Joan: That day. Yep, that day.
>
> Kate: That was a pretty funny day, wasn't it?
>
> Joan: The cat was jumping all over the brook trying to get out of the shallow water.
>
> Kate: That week was also the week, when the utility company finally strung electricity to our house too.
>
> Joan: Oh no, the days before that week, we had no electricity. We were like living in the wild.
>
> Kate: We were living in the wild.
>
> Joan: Actually, I really longed to live in the wild of Tennessee again.
>
> Kate: I knew you had a wild streak in you.
>
> Joan: What wild streak?
>
> Kate: The wild streak that made mama pull her hair and gnash her teeth.
>
> Joan: That wild streak?
>
> Kate: Yes, that wild streak.

Comment: I think you're saying that they both mean about the same thing, but it's not clear.

Answer (score -2):

When used as a non-demonstrative determiner, 'that' is synonymous with 'the'.

Comment: Can you clarify by illustrating the demonstrative- and non-demonstrative-determiner usages of 'that'?

Comment: I can't demonstrate the demonstrative usage via text...

Comment: I don't think he/she understands the meaning of "demonstrative usage".

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a she. That/the beard is a dead giveaway.

Comment: 'That thing' means the same thing as 'the thing', unless the speaker is pointing to something.  {'That' is also a relative pronoun, so I had to specify its use.}